# Obtener mes de índice en DataFrame de pandas

Tags: pandas

Tengo este `DataFrame`:

```
df.head()

    FechaI              Precio
0   01/01/2021 00:00    1.237
1   04/01/2021 08:52    1.233
2   05/01/2021 08:31    1.219
3   11/01/2021 09:36    1.229
4   14/01/2021 09:55    1.239

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 60 entries, 0 to 59
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   FechaI  60 non-null     object 
 1   Precio  60 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 1.1+ KB
```

El formato de las fechas es `dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm`.

Quiero convertir la columna `FechaI` a un formato `time` para trabajar con las fechas.

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['FechaI'])
indice = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.values)
df2 = df.set_index(indice)
df2.drop('FechaI',axis=1,inplace=True)
df2.head()

                    Precio
2021-01-01 00:00:00 1.237
2021-04-01 08:52:00 1.233
2021-05-01 08:31:00 1.219
2021-11-01 09:36:00 1.229
2021-01-14 09:55:00 1.239
```

Parece que ha transpuesto algunas posiciones del mes y día (??). De hecho:

```
df2.index.month
Int64Index([ 1,  4,  5, 11,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  5,  9,  2,  2,  2,
             2,  1,  6,  9, 11,  2,  2,  2,  1,  6,  9, 11,  2,  2,  2,  1,  6,
             9, 11,  2,  2,  2,  1,  6,  9, 11,  2,  2,  2,  1,  6,  9, 11,  2,
             2,  2],
           dtype='int64')
```

Cuando todos los meses se corresponden a enero y febrero. ¿Cómo se puede corregir esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que el hecho de que en la cadena de fecha aparezca también una hora le confunde.

Si especificas el formato de la cadena en el parámetro `format` de `.to_datetime()` se consigue que lo interprete correctamente:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['FechaI'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

produce:

```
0   2021-01-01 00:00:00
1   2021-01-04 08:52:00
2   2021-01-05 08:31:00
3   2021-01-11 09:36:00
4   2021-01-14 09:55:00
```

que ya puedes usar como índice. Si quieres quedarte sólo con la fecha e ignorar la hora puedes acceder a `.dt.date`. Es decir:

```
df.FechaI = pd.to_datetime(df.FechaI, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").dt.date
df = df.set_index("FechaI")
```

Y obtienes:

```
            Precio
FechaI            
2021-01-01   1.237
2021-01-04   1.233
2021-01-05   1.219
2021-01-11   1.229
2021-01-14   1.239
```